# Can I offline render an audio file with dynamic tempo?

Tags: audio, core-audio, audio-recording, audiokit

I'm developing a karaoke application.
I try to provide a funny function.
can I use [AudioKit](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit) to offline render an audio file with time based dynamic tempo value?
Click the below image and you can get it very soon.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGGAQ.png)

---

And I post some code here.

```swift
// I want to change the tempo for bgm audio file dynamically
self.timePitch = AKTimePitch(self.bgmPlayer)
// here I set the initialized rate value to time Pitch
self.timePitch.rate = 1.0
// support iOS10+
self.out = AKOfflineRenderNode()
self.timePitch.connect(to: self.out)
// make the renderer as AudioKit.out
AudioKit.output = self.out
do {
    try AudioKit.start()
} catch {
    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
}
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "output.caf")
// get total duration
let duration = self.duration()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    do {
        let avAudioTime = AVAudioTime(sampleTime: 0, atRate:self.out.avAudioNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate)
        // start play BGM
        self.bgmPlayer.play(at: avAudioTime)
        // and render it to an offline file
        try self.out?.renderToURL(url, duration: duration)
        // **********
        // Question:
        // Can I change the tempo value when rendering?
        // **********

        // stop when finished
        self.bgmPlayer.stop()
    } catch {
        debugPrint(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how the dynamic tempo is realized - you can send the audio through time/pitch shifting and render the result.

Comment: Thanks very much. Can I change tempo for frame position when I prepared the pipeline and started offline rendering ?

Comment: Right, I see the dilemma.  Sample accurate modification of the timing of the tempo/pitch modification.  As you're running the samples in the rendering, you'll have to convert the activation times to sample times and change parameters appropriately.